# generating sums of data according to values of a variable

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data similar to this:

```
Hosp    Score   Var1    Var2    Var3
1       0       5       3       0
1       1       10      8       1
1       2       11      8       2
1       3       5       3       2
2       0       6       4       0
2       2       10      6       1
2       3       10      7       2
3       1       4       3       2
etc...
```

there are approx 800 Hosps and 4 levels of the factor score (0,1,2,3). Some Hosps do not have an observation for a particular levels of score

I would like to produce a new data frame where the variables Var1, Var2 and Var3 are summed. So using the data above this would give

```
Hosp    Var1    Var2    Var3
1       32      22      5
2       26      17      3
3       4       3       2
```

This would be trivial in SQL (and I guess it is in R too!) but the only way I have found so far is with a loop, which adds a new row each time Hosp changes and increments the variables when it doesn't change (of course the data is sorted on Hosp).

Is there a slick way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aggregate()`. Assuming your `data.frame` is named "temp", use:

```
aggregate(list(Var1 = temp$Var1, Var2 = temp$Var2, Var3 = temp$Var3), 
          list(Hosp = temp$Hosp), sum)
#   Hosp Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    1   31   22    5
# 2    2   26   17    3
# 3    3    4    3    2
```

For a `slick` way to do this, use the formula notation for `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(cbind(Var1, Var2, Var3) ~ Hosp, temp, sum)
```

Note, however, that there is a difference in how `NA` values are treated with the default `data.frame` method and the `formula` method.

#### Update

You mentioned in your original question using SQL. I don't have much experience with SQL, but there is also the `sqldf` package, with which you can do the following:

```
sqldf("select Hosp, 
      sum(Var1) `Var1`, sum(Var2) `Var2`, sum(Var3) `Var3` 
      from temp 
      group by Hosp")
#   Hosp Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    1   31   22    5
# 2    2   26   17    3
# 3    3    4    3    2
```

Comment: @longrob, also check out the "apply" family of functions for other types of aggregation that might be useful for this type of work. The "doBy" package is also useful.

Answer (score 3):

a `data.table` solution for memory, coding and time efficiency.

Given that you are used to using `SQL` you should find the syntax for `data.table` straightforward, once you have looked at the vignettes for `data.table`.

```
# assuming your data is in DF
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)

DT[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = hosp, .SDcols = c('Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3')]
```

In this case the you can use the short hand `lapply(.SD, FUN)`, setting `.SDcols` to be the variables to run `lapply` upon.

A more verbose, but `SQL`-like approach  to produce the same results would be

```
DT[, list(Var1 = sum(Var1), Var2 =sum(Var2), Var3 = sum(Var3)), by = hosp]
```

but why would you write all this extra code when you don't need to!

Answer (score 1):

Building on the [solution by mrdwab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12857499), but providing a shorter syntax:

```
aggregate(temp[3:5], temp[1], sum)
```

This uses the fact that a data frame is a list, and single bracket subsetting will therefore produce a data frame with a subset of the columns. This avoids all the `list` calls.

---

Yet another alternative:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(temp[-2], .(Hosp), colSums, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This splits the data frame into chunks by `Hosp`, and computes column sums for each such chunk the way `colSums(chunk, na.rm = TRUE)` would do it. The `[-2]` drops the `Score` column from the input, so you won't get a sum for that.

Alas, as mrdwab correctly pointed out in a comment below, the above will also sum the `Hosp` column. My first fix to the problem was the following:

```
ddply(t[-2], .(Hosp), function(d){colSums(d[-1], na.rm = TRUE)})
```

This will drop the `Hosp` column from the argument to `colSums`, so that it doesn't override the original column of that name which `ddply` provides by default. On the whole, not a pretty solution any more, and neither a fast one. But as it does have the function operating on the chunks explicitely spelled out, it is very flexible, so I'll leave it for reference.

In yet another comment, mrdwab proposed a better solution:

```
ddply(temp[-2], .(Hosp), numcolwise(sum))
```

This works, because `numcolwise`, which is based on `colwise`, internally calls `strip_splits` which in turn removes those columns which were used to perform the split, i.e. `Hosp` in this case. All of the functions in the previous sentence come from `plyr`.

Comment: Careful, as you've done this, the `plyr` alternative also sums the "Hosp" column!

Comment: Edit your answer to read the following, and you've got my +1 for forcing me to do some research (I'm generally more of a base R guy): `ddply(temp[-2], .(Hosp), numcolwise(sum))`